# Create an EGLContext in C++ and bind it to a Java GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

i try to create an EGLContext in C++ and bint it to a GLSurfaceView.
After some research on google and even here, i don't see something close to my problem.

It is possible to do this ?

I already know that i can do a NativeActivity, but i also need to use Java library for Loading Image, Audio, make HttpRequest, get Device information, etc.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: GLSurfaceView creates its own EGL context.  It provides a weird array of hooks to tweak the EGLConfig, but it really wants to create its own context on its renderer thread.  Can you let GLSurfaceView set up the EGLContext, and then access that from your other code?  (What are you trying to do?)

Comment: The main problem for is that it's some script which init the EGLcontext 'on demand', that's why i wanted to create it in C++, but if there is a way to pass the EGLContext from Java to C++, i think it should be a good start

Comment: The easiest way to pass it around is with `eglMakeCurrent()` and `eglGetCurrentContext()`.  For a `GLSurfaceView` the context should only ever be used from its Renderer thread, though, and you should never have the same context be used from multiple threads simultaneously.  So ideally you let `GLSurfaceView` create the context and then call native functions from its callbacks; the context will be current on that thread so you don't need to explicitly pass anything.

Comment: ok, will try like this, thanks @fadden